# Can I mount a 3 gang box vertically?

Tags: electrical

I need to fit 3 switches into a narrow space. Is there any rule against mounting a 3 gang box so that it is taller than it is wide? I will be using two single pole switches and one three way switch.

Comment: The also do sell 3 switches in a single device "single gang triple switch".

Comment: ...or you could do a 2-gang box with a single switch and then two switches in the other gang. That would let you have one "normal" switch, which might be nice if you're fumbling around in the dark for a light.

Comment: There are always [other](http://www.westwayelectricsupply.com/tm8113-wcc-decorator-combo-sp-sp-3w-wh-cc.html?gclid=CIKA5eWkksMCFaU7MgodZSsACQ) options as well. Pricey but probably less "unusual" looking.

Comment: Also unusual functioning, since the switches will be sideways...will on be left or right?

Comment: The problem with triplex switches is that they will almost certainly overload the wiring capacity of a 1-gang box. A single and duplex switch in a two-gang is usually OK depending on the wiring scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely fine. There is no rule or code prohibiting it that I know of.

Comment: I did see the Pass & Seymore combo switch but didn't like the cost and worry about replacing in the future. One of the switches will be used a lot more than the other two. I will probably use three rocker type switches mounted horizontally. One will be a three way circuit so left or right on/off won't matter. The other two I will wire to be on when the left side is pushed in. May look a little strange at first but I don't like the look of separate switches stacked either. The drywall cut would be more difficult too. Thanks to all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few [3 Switch](http://www.legrand.us/passandseymour/light-switches/decorator/tm8113wcc.aspx#.VLf5bIcWnDk) Switches and even a few [4 Switch](http://www.legrand.us/passandseymour/light-switches/decorator/tm81111bkcc.aspx#.VLf5M4cWnDk) Switches. They make them for 1 or 2 circuit wiring. So you could have a 14/3 going to the box and run 2 switches on one circuit and the 3rd/4th switch on the 2nd circuit.  The Wiring isn't too bad in a normal box. If you are putting in the box, just put in the Deep version.